# PyQGIS: qgis:refactorfields won't accept FIELDS_MAPPING data

Tags: python, pyqgis

I'm trying to create a PyQGIS script that changes length values of all shapefiles in a specified folder. I would like to save disk space by setting all length values to 2 which Refactor Fields will automatically change to the highest value in that row. I've successfully put together a script that converts shapefiles with a known amount of rows (I copy the FIELDS_MAPPING section).

```
import processing
import glob
import os

path = "C:/path"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.shp"):
    vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, os.path.splitext(os.basename(layer))[0], 'ogr')
    fields = vLayer.pendingFields()
    field_names = [field.name() for field in fields ]
    processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
                      vLayer,
                      [{'name': str(fields.field(0).name())[0:],
                        'type': fields.field(0).type(),
                        'length': 2,
                        'precision': 0,
                        'expression': str(fields.field(0).name())[0:]
                      }],
                      path + vLayer.name() + '_refactored.shp')
```

From this I wanted to create a script that converts all rows.

```
import processing
import glob
import os

path = "C:/path"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.shp"):
    vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer,os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0], 'ogr')
    fields = vLayer.pendingFields()
    field_names = [field.name() for field in fields ]
    i = 0
    stitch = "["
    while(i < len(fields)):
        nameParam = fields.field(i).name()
        nameParam = nameParam[0:]
        typeParam = fields.field(i).type()
        stitch = stitch + "{'name': '" + str(nameParam) + "', 'type': " + str(typeParam) + ", 'length': 2, 'precision': 0, 'expression': '" + str(nameParam) + "'}"
        if len(fields)-1 != i:
            stitch = stitch + ", "
        i = i + 1
    stitch = stitch + "]"
    processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
                      vLayer,
                      stitch,
                      path + vLayer.name() + '_refactored.shp')
```

This code does not work. I've tried running `processing.runalg` using the `exec()` function in python. It produces the same results. The PyQGIS console points towards the `stitch` variable (the data inside, not the variable itself) and displays a data error.

Any ideas why this won't work?

**UPDATE**

The error:

```
Error: Wrong parameter value: [{'name': <name>, 'type': <type>, 'length': 2, 'precision': 0,'expression': <name>}, {'name': <name>, 'type': <type>, 'length': 2, 'precision': 0,'expression': <name>}]
```

The values in `<>` are generated from the `.name()` and `.type()` functions.

Comment: Could you add the error text to your question?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: To clarify - are you running this script outside of QGIS?

Comment: No, I'm running the script from the python editor in QGIS.